# Number format in mathematica

Tags: output-formatting

Is there any way to write a number in out put in following format?
`{1E-7,2E-7,3E-7,4E-7,}`
I want to show number with E

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
list = Range[1, 5, .5] 10^-5

(*  {0.00001, 0.000015, 0.00002, 0.000025, 0.00003, 0.000035, 0.00004, \
0.000045, 0.00005}  *)

ScientificForm[list, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "E", #3}] &)]
```

[image]